# Creating graphs with specific formatting from user highlighted cells

Tags: excel, vba

I am attempting to create a macro that can be used on a variety of data sets that will create graphs with standardized, specific formatting. I haven't actually changed the formatting specifics yet because I am trying to get the general code to run first.

I am new to VBA, and am somewhat confused. I know that some of my logic may be incorrect as I switch from the chrt variable to the cht variable, but can't tell why even the basic portion doesn't work. I have tried different variable declarations to no avail.

```
Sub fullPageLine()

Dim rng As Range
Dim chrt As Object
Dim cht As Chart

'Your data range for the chart
  Set rng = ActiveSheet.Selection

'Create a chart
  Set chrt = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add( _
    Left:=ActiveCell.Left, _
    Width:=450, _
    Top:=ActiveCell.Top, _
    Height:=250)

'Give chart some data
  chrt.Chart.SetSourceData Source:=rng

'Determine the chart type
  chrt.Chart.ChartType = xlLine

    'Reposition Title
        With chrt.Chart.ChartTitle
          .Left = 100
          .Top = 50
           End With

            Set cht = chrt

            'Format Font Size
                cht.ChartArea.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Size = 7
                cht.ChartTitle.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Size = 8.4

            'Format Font Type
                cht.ChartArea.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Name = "Arial"
                cht.ChartTitle.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Name = "Arial"


            'Change chart series fill color
                cht.SeriesCollection(1).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(91, 155, 213)
                cht.SeriesCollection(2).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(91, 155, 213)
                cht.SeriesCollection(3).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(91, 155, 213)
                cht.SeriesCollection(4).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(91, 155, 213)
                cht.SeriesCollection(5).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(91, 155, 213)
                cht.SeriesCollection(6).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(91, 155, 213)
                cht.SeriesCollection(7).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(91, 155, 213)

End Sub
```

When attempting to create the graph, I get an error message saying "object doesn't support this property or method". This issue persists even after I have commented out everything beyond the chart type, so the initial code to create the chart won't even work.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Small tip just to warm you up: `ActiveSheet` does not have a property `Selection`. Both `ActiveSheet` and `Selection` are properties of `Application`, so they are at the same "level". Try `Set rng = Selection`. The rest of the code seems to be on the good track (needs some small adjustments) so let me know if you need further help or you get stuck. I can see that you are already proceeding nicely and would be great if you could figure it out yourself. Good luck!

Comment: If you get errors when running your code, it's most useful to note on which line you see the error - otherwise we're just guessing.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not getting any line specific errors, just an error message and a graph output that isn't what I am looking for

Comment: hope  @Justyna MK comment solved your problem. if not, sometimes `Chrt.Chart.HasTitle = True` and   `Chrt.Chart.ChartTitle.Text = "Some thing"` may help.Also depending on excel version may try with `FullSeriesCollection` instead of  `SeriesCollection`.Otherwise  I concur fully with Justyna MK that you are already proceeding nicely.

Comment: yes, it was helpful, and now it produces a basic graph. However, I am now getting an "object required" error whenever I try any formatting. I am clearly misunderstanding something with my initial declarations, and would love to know what that might be. Thanks for all the help!